# xsl grouping tags into parent

Tags: xml, xslt

my xml is :

```
 <Row>
        <one>1</one>
        <two>2</two>
        <three>3</tree>
        <four>4</four>
        <...
        <...
        <...
    </Row>
```

and My expected result is :

```
<Row>
     <main>
            <value type="one_type">
              <stringValue>1</stringValue>
            </value>
            <value type="two_type">
              <stringValue>2</stringValue>
            </value>
      </main>

 <others>
        <three>3</tree>
        <four>4</four>
        <...
        <...
        <...
 <others>

</Row>
```

and my xsl is :

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="one|two">
    <main>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="one">
                <value type="one_type">
                    <stringValue>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                    </stringValue>
                </value> 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <value type="two_type">
                    <stringValue>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                    </stringValue>
                </value> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </main>

    </xsl:template>
```

But this returns two different main tags  and I want all the tags to be under the main tag.
Any Idea how to do this ? i thought if else will give me the desired result but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired output with following adjustment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <main>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </main>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="one|two">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'one'">
            <value type="one_type">
                <stringValue>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </stringValue>
            </value>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <value type="two_type">
                <stringValue>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </stringValue>
            </value>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<Row>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
</Row>
```

Ouput:

```
<main>
<value type="one_type">
  <stringValue>1</stringValue>
</value>
<value type="two_type">
  <stringValue>2</stringValue>
</value>
</main>
```

So the element `main` is only written once - in an additional template matching `Row` - as a wrapper for the other elements written by your current template matching `one` and `two`.

**Update** for the edited question:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Row">
<Row>
    <main>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="one | two "/>
    </main>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="three| four"/>
</Row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="one|two">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'one'">
            <value type="one_type">
                <stringValue>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </stringValue>
            </value>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <value type="two_type">
                <stringValue>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </stringValue>
            </value>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="three|four">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<Row>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
  <three>1</three>
  <four>2</four>
</Row>
```

Output:

```
<Row>
<main>
  <value type="one_type">
     <stringValue>1</stringValue>
  </value>
  <value type="two_type">
     <stringValue>2</stringValue>
  </value>
</main>
<three>1</three>
<four>2</four>
</Row>
```

**Update** for the second adjustment of OP:

As example input xml for 6 entries:

Input:

```
<Row>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
  <three>3</three>
  <four>4</four>
  <five>5</five>
  <six>6</six>
</Row>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Row">
<Row>
    <main>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="one | two "/>
    </main>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::one | self::two)]"/>
</Row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="one|two">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'one'">
            <value type="one_type">
                <stringValue>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </stringValue>
            </value>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <value type="two_type">
                <stringValue>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </stringValue>
            </value>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Row>
<main>
  <value type="one_type">
     <stringValue>1</stringValue>
  </value>
  <value type="two_type">
     <stringValue>2</stringValue>
  </value>
</main>
<three>3</three>
<four>4</four>
<five>5</five>
<six>6</six>
</Row>
```

The adjustment is to apply templates in the template matching `row` to all nodes except the elements named `one` and `two` using  `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::one | self::two)]"/>` and changing the template that just copies the nodes below the `main` tag to match all nodes - `<xsl:template match="node()">`

Comment: If you really want to make a test inside the template then you `test="self::one"`. But usually it suffices to write a match pattern.

Comment: I have changed abit my question , can you see the changes ? I need the one two tags in separate main tag inside row tag. can you edit your answer ?

Comment: @user3379892 Glad I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer or one of the other answers so the question will be marked as closed. In case you don't know how this works, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Comment: thanks for the help. I have edited my question again to be more generic. I need all the other tags that are not one and two , into others tag.

Comment: @user3379892 Just updated my answer for the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any grouping in that sample, you seem to want to transform `Row` to `main` and `one` to `value type="one_type"` and `two` to `value type="two_type"`.

So your start with

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

is fine, then add

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
  <main>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </main>
</xsl:template>
```

and then

```
<xsl:template match="one | two">
  <value type="{local-name()}_type">
    <stringValue>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </stringValue>
  </value>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your edited question, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <main>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
        </main>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="three|four"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="one|two">
    <value type="{local-name()}_type">
        <stringValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </stringValue>
    </value>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you are not sure which elements other than `<one>` and `<two>` can appear, change this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="three|four"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::one or self::two)]"/>
```

Comment: great! this was helpful