# xsl group tags into parents groups

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml :

```
<Row>
        <one>1</one>
        <two>2</two>
        <three>3</tree>
        <four>4</four>
        <five>5</five>
        <six>6</six>
        <seven>7</seven>
        <...
        <...
        <...
        <...
        <...
 </Row>
```

and I want to group one two tag into main tag and all the rest (could be more hundred of these ) into other tag :

Expected result :

```
<Row>

   <main>
        <one>1</one>
        <two>2</two>
    <main>  

   <others> 
        <three>3</tree>
        <four>4</four>
         <five>1</five>
        <six>2</six>
        <seven>3</seven>
        <...
        <...
        <...
        <...
        <...
    <others> 

 </Row>
```

My xslt is :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
        <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template match="Row">

          <main>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
          </main>

          <others>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>   
          </others>

        </xsl:template>
```

But I get on the other tag also one and two , I want one and two to be only in the main tag.

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699292/xsl-grouping-tags-into-parent

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the templates twice on one and two. First explicitely, second implicitely in your second match : node()|@*.
Just filter them out from this second match.
This xpath should do the job (not tested, too early in the morning here for me) :

```
<xsl:template match="Row">

      <main>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
      </main>

      <others>
        <!-- No need to apply on attributes (@*), 
        unless you explicitely want to add rows attributes to others element.-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(name()='one' or name()='two')]"/>   
      </others>

    </xsl:template>
```